# WildFly 8.2 auto deploy configuration

Tags: wildcard, wildfly-8

How to configure WildFly 8.2.1 to:

1. Not auto-deploy from "deployments" folder when server running
2. Always deploy from "deployments" whent starting up, ignoring previous deploy result

If I set scan-enabled="false" for deployment-scanner, WildFly didnt deploy at startup even new files.
When scan-enabled="true", WildFly didn't deploy files that failed to deploy at previous start up, but not changed.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid auto deploy set `auto-deploy-zipped="false" auto-deploy-exploded="false"` for deployment-scanner in standalone.xml.

But whenever you want to deploy another file then you have to add MARKER FILES for it.

For example, the marker file to indicate the HelloWorld.war file should be deployed named `HelloWorld.war.dodeploy` in deployments folder and file should have content - **HelloWorld.war**.

Then only it will deploy your new file automatically.

Refer [**this**](http://pvrworld-wildfly.blogspot.in/2016/11/avoid-auto-deploy-of-content-in-wildfly.html) and [**this**](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Scanner+configuration) link for some more info.

Comment: If scan-enabled="false" then WildFly will ignore marker files at startup and at runtime

Comment: I have following entry in my standalone.xml
<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-zipped="false" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/>
Which works fine with marker file at server startup in wildfly 8.2.1

Comment: if attribute scan-enabled missed then scan-enabled=true

Comment: Though its true, it will not auto deploy your new added files without adding MARKER file.

Answer (score 0):

If scan-enabled="false" then WildFly will ignore marker files at startup and at runtime. Alsow WildFly will ignore all deployments in deploy folder, even if that deployments was successfully deployed before.

Left only 2 ways:

1. Set scan-interval less than 1 (with scan-enabled="true"). It will
   enable only one scan at startup. After that WildFly also will ignore
   any changes in deploy folder
2. Deploy through admin console